# Spring Cloud CLI installation with Spring Boot 1.4 CLI - ClassNotFoundException - org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandFactory

Tags: spring-boot, command-line-interface, spring-cloud

I installed springboot from brew - brew install springbok
This gave me 1.4.0.RELEASE

Further i tried installing spring cli to run spring encrypt in local

spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

From then any spring commands are throwing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/cli/command/CommandFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:89)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.addServiceLoaderCommands(SpringCli.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:48)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

What is missing? i remember this was working earlier with lower version of springboot some months earlier.

Comment: You didn't provide details of your configuration. Nobody is going to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of the issue. You can track things here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/issues/20

The workaround is to use spring boot 1.3.6.RELEASE

Comment: how can i get to a specific spring boot version? https://github.com/pivotal/homebrew-tap/blob/master/springboot.rb --> This is only 1.4 specific, there are no previous branches/tags available

Comment: @Snickers3192 what doesn't work? The latest version of the cli is 1.3.4 and uses spring boot 1.5.x, so this issue is moot.